# Extending SVN to handle files within ZIP or other file types

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, zip, file-comparison

I've been editing some nuget packages that are under SVN for the past few months now. Is there a way to extend SVN so that when you try to compare changes from one file version to the other, it handles files within zip files?

Nuget packages are basically a folder with a specific structure, filled with different plain-text-based files (xml, txt. etc) and zipped together with a file extention of `.nupkg`, the idea would be that instead of trying and pass the .nupkg itself to the file comparison tool, [`WinMerge`](http://winmerge.org/) in my case, SVN would first unpack the package and then pass the root folder of the content (or a self-generated `./` folder if needed) to the file comparison tool.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is comparing the archive files at the client side. You can set a custom diff viewer in TortoiseSVN instead of the built-in tool.

You need to do 2 things:

1. A tool that can diff the files within zip. An example is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) with [archive support](http://manual.winmerge.org/Configuration.html) (Section 8)
2. Set this tool in TortoiseSVN as your defualt diff/merge viewer. Right-click in Windows explorer or desktop -> TortoiseSVN -> External Programs

Comment: I really like your answer but I'm struggling with setting up `archive support` in WinMerge. I'll get back to you when I get it working :)

Comment: Other options are [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), [zipdiff](http://zipdiff.sourceforge.net/), [ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp)